# How do I graph this set?

Tags: geometry, functions, game-theory

Please consider the following exercise:

*Suppose that we are considering a game between two players with the following game bimatrix
$$
(A,B) = \begin{pmatrix} (2,1) & (0,0)\\ (0,0) & (1,2) \end{pmatrix}
$$
Suppose that the players cannot cooperate. The feasible set of non-cooperative solutions is given by
$$
\{(u,v) = (p^TAq, p^TBq): p\in X^*, q \in Y^*\}
$$
Graph the set of non-cooperative solutions.*

**My approach:** I know that the set of feasible solutions lie inside the convex hull of the points $(1,2), (2,1), (0,0)$ as these are the values corresponding to the four possible combinations of pure strategies ($p = 1$ with $q = 1$ or $q = 0$ and $p = 0$ with $q = 1$ or $q = 0$). In order to determine the solution within this convex set, I tried to write out the definition of $(u,v)$. Suppose that we have $p = (p_1, p_2)$ and $ q = (q_1,q_2)$. Then 
$$
(u,v) = (2p_1q_1 + p_2q_2, p_1q_1 + 2p_2q_2)
$$
I think that this is correct, but unfortunately this is a function that depends on four variables (and cannot be plotted in three dimensions).

**The solution:** Apparently the graph should look like this:

[image]

This graph comes with the following note: *the curve joining $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ has parametric form $(x,y) = (1 - 2a + 3a^2, 2 - 4a + 3a^2)$*.

**My question:** How do you arrive at the form of $(x,y)$ as given in the solution? How do you solve this exercise? I feel like I always struggle when visualising functions, or when trying to come up with alternative expressions for sets. I have no idea how I would have been able to arrive at $(x,y) = (1 - 2a + 3a^2, 2 - 4a + 3a^2)$. Is there a general way of approaching these kinds of problems, or do you just have to spend a lot of time on them to get a feel for it?

Comment: For the curve $(x,y)=(1-2a+3a^2,2-4a+3a^2)$, you may just solve the equation for $a$ and a variable ($x$ or $y$) and put it in the relation of $a$ and the other variable. $1-2a+3a^2 = x$ gives $$a=\frac{1\pm \sqrt{3x-2}}3\qquad (3x-2\ge 0)$$ and by putting the value of $a$ we got, $$y = (1-2a+3a^2)+1-2a = x+\frac {1\mp 2 \sqrt{3x-2}} 3.$$ And I think you know how to graph those two functions. To be more exact, you may put some simple values, such as $a=-1,0,1,2$, which gives $(6,9),(1,2),(2,1),(9,6)$ in order.

Comment: @KanuKim Thank you for your reply. My question is more about how I should get to $(x,y) = (1- 2a + 3a^2, 2 - 4a + 3a^2)$ though!

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question. Can you notice me what are $X^*$ and $Y^*$ in this problem?

Comment: Player I and player II's respective set of (mixed) strategies.

Comment: So you mean $X^*=Y^*=\{(t_1,t_2):t_1+t_2=  1, t_i\ge 0\}$, right? Then we have $p_2 = 1-p_1$ and $q_2 = 1-q_1$ so that ($p_1,q_1\in [0,1]$) $$\begin{aligned} (u,v) &= (2p_1q_1+(1-p_1)(1-q_1), p_1q_1+2(1-p_1)(1-q_1)) \\&= (3p_1q_1-p_1-q_1+1,3p_1q_1-2p_1-2q_1+2). \end{aligned} $$
Note that $ p_1+q_1 \ge 2\sqrt{p_1 q_1} $ and the equality holds when $p_1=q_1$. So when $\sqrt{p_1q_1}=a^2$ ($a\ge 0$), $u\le 1-2a+3a^2$ and $v \le 1-2a+3a^2$, you can get a 'boundary' curve $ (x,y)=(1-2a+3a^2,2-4a+3a^2)$.

Comment: To prove that the region is as in the figure, consider the following linear transformation:
$$ A = \frac 2 3\begin{pmatrix}2&-1\\-1&2\end{pmatrix}:\quad (1,2)^T\mapsto (0,2)^T,\quad (2,1)^T\mapsto (2,0)^T. $$
Then by some calculation, $A(u,v)^T = 2(p_1q_1, p_2q_2)^T.$ ($p_1+p_2=q_1+q_2=1$.) This can be drawn easily, and the result is $\sqrt x + \sqrt y = 1$, that is, $ (x,y)=(a^2,(1-a)^2)$. By taking $A^{-1}$, we can get the desired region and the boundary $ (x,y)=(1-2a+3a^2,2-4a+3a^2).$

I don't think this will fulfill your question because the precedure seems like *a posteriori*.